# Animating a View Like This Example

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I am facing a problem when trying to animate a view.  When the user clicks on the advanced search button, it is navigating this view and the animation starts, but it is not correct.  How can I animate a view when the user clicks on the advanced search button?

(I want to make this type of animation : )

http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/041_TopPanelWithJquery/demo/index.html

Are there any good tutorials that will help me in this matter?

---

**Some existing code from a comment**

```
AddSearchView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 65, 310, 148);
//CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:AddSearchView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
AddSearchView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 57, 310, 148);
//CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You can't animate anything in Xcode, Xcode is a development environment that helps you write code. Do you want to animate something with Cocoa (for the Mac) or Cocoa Touch (for the iPhone and iPad) in Objective-C?

Comment: my animating code is AddSearchView.frame   = CGRectMake(10, 65, 310, 148);//CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
 [self.view addSubview:AddSearchView];
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
 AddSearchView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 57, 310, 148);//CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480);
 [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: So your use of `UIView` reveals that you're talking about Cocoa Touch. I'll edit your question to indicate that, which might help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIView`'s `setAnimationDidStopSelector` method to call another function once the current animation is complete. I have used this to link animations which heavy relied on timing. For that particular animation, I would try animating the `UIView`'s frame property.

Also consider using `CAKeyframeAnimation`. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html